# Counting number of valid strings

Tags: combinatorics

> Call a length $n$ string "valid" if it is formed from the set $\{A, B,
> C, D, E, F, G\}$ and it contains at least one of A, B, C, D

Find the number of valid strings using Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion?

So I guess let S1, S2, S3, S4 be sets containing an A, B, C, and D.

So we want cardinality of intersection of all of these sets? I can do it with inclusion exclusion, and  I can easily get $|S_i| = 7^n-6^n$, but computing the intersections $|S1 \cap S2|$ (strings with length $n$ with both letters present) and such are hard.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it was a typo

Comment: Yes. corrected. I must use inclusion exclusion

Comment: Do you mean it must include at least one each of all four letters $A,B,C,D$?  Or at least one of one of them?

Comment: It must have at least one of each of all four letters of $A, B, C, D$. So, "DDDD" is not good. But "ABCD" is good.

Answer (score 1):

Since you could compute $|S_i|=7^n-6^5$, it's easy to apply the same conclusion to find $|S_1 \cap S_2|=7^n-5^n$ and so on. So if you want to count the number of strings "At least one of them is included":
$$|S_A \cup S_B \cup S_C \cup S_D|=4(7^n-6^n)-6(7^n-5^n)+4(7^n-4^n)-(7^n-3^n)$$
But if you want to count the number of strings "At least one of each of them is included":
$$|S_A \cap S_B \cap S_C \cap S_D|=7^n-|S_A' \cup S_B' \cup S_C' \cup S_D'|=7^n-4\times6^n+6\times5^n-4\times4^n+3^n$$
That in above we first use complement and Demorgan's Law, and then expand it like previous part using PIE. The fact that the number of string of length $n$, that haven't $k$ specific elements of an alphabet with $m$ elements, is obviously $(m-k)^n$. At last the coefficients is $\binom{k}{i}$, where $k$ is number of selected elements, in this case $4$, and $i$ is the parameter of PIE.

Comment: Thank you Ali but wouldnt $7^n - 5^n$ be the number of ways to have at least one of the two letters? I want to compute the number of letters with at least one of each A,B,C,D. So for example, ABCD is valid. But ABCC is invalid.

Comment: @astronomer6353 I included both in my answer.

Comment: How'd you get the expression for "at least one of each of them is included"? Been trying to figure that out

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks, I edit it.

Comment: @astronomer6353 I include some explanations. Hope Help!